# Redmine, upload file with cURL

Tags: cookies, curl, redmine

I'm trying to upload files to Redmine from a shell script with cURL:

```
url=localhost/redmine
curl -c cookie -F username=admin -F password=admin $url/login
curl -b cookie -F 'attachments[1][file]'=@file $url/projects/test/files/new
```

The first `curl` stores the session cookie into the file `cookie` after a successful login. But the second `curl` to upload always fails. Redmine's mysterious error message is

```
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed
Only get requests are allowed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Redmine has an API for script access

Comment: Is it a REST-API or a server side Ruby API?

Comment: REST API: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
curl -c cookie -F username=admin -F password=admin $url/login
curl -b cookie -F attachments[0][file]=@file $url/projects/test/files/new
```

It seems Ruby belongs to the family of rare languages that index arrays from zero, as `attachments[0][file]` is OK, while `attachments[1][file]` is not.